# SQL using a string executed as cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, database-cursor

I want to use a variable I pass to a stored procedure to be used as table name in my query to be used in cursor to be used to send email. My snippet sample is below:

```
--DECLARE @getemail CURSOR
--SET @getemail = CURSOR FOR
DECLARE @getemail CURSOR FOR 
SET @recipientquery =  'SELECT * FROM '+@tableA+''
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @recipientquery
```

Questions is why I am getting error in the for part saying:

> Incorrect syntax

What is the correct syntax to use when using a string query after for in cursor?

Answer (score 1):

It would be :

```
set @recipientquery = 'Declare  getemail CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM'+@tableA

exec sp_executesql @recipientquery


OPEN getemail
```

Comment: i see let me confirm ill be back here asap

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect syntax near after `for` statement.

Please find this link for syntax and more info [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
DECLARE vend_cursor CURSOR  
    FOR SELECT * FROM Purchasing.Vendor  
OPEN vend_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM vend_cursor;
```

Or may be this is the issue 
you forgot comment your declare cursor which is not used over there

```
--DECLARE @getemail CURSOR FOR    --- (here cursor for what...? )
SET @recipientquery =  'SELECT * FROM '+@tableA+''
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @recipientquery
```

Or you may use dynamic sql to create your query

```
Create table demotable  ( id int, name nvarchar(max) )

declare @tableA nvarchar(max)
set @tableA = 'demotable'

declare @recipientquery nvarchar(max)   
SET @recipientquery =  'DECLARE getemail CURSOR FOR  
                        SELECT * FROM '+@tableA+''
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @recipientquery
open getemail


close getemail
deallocate getemail
```

If this didn't work then please post your whole query, to get the exact scenario.

Comment: that is the whole query also you sample is different from my sample just by looking. I want to use a query string not a direct select query `SET @recipientquery =  'SELECT * FROM '+@tableA+''
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @recipientquery`

Comment: how you are getting this value of @tableA, cause if you are not selecting any row from table then there is no need to use `cursor`.cursor is use to iterate loop and there is no loop seen in your query.

Comment: I want to use a variable I pass to SP to be used as table name in my query to be used in cursor to be used to send email.

Comment: i need the cursor..your update does not solve my issue

Comment: then you need to apply cursor on calling this stored procedure, here you are passing just one @tableA directly, so no need to call cursor for that.

Comment: @guradio; I updated my ans in case 3, you may get your solution.

Comment: i tried the 3rd part , that is all the query i have but still same error on for saying `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197249/discussion-between-darkrob-and-guradio).